# can a SQL UNIQUE constraint have conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to modify the following constraint so that it doesnt apply to negative AMOUNTS. **Is that possible?**  I've played around with the syntax in the SSMS for a while now and it hasn't likeed anything I've come up with.

```
ALTER TABLE Payments
ADD CONSTRAINT Unique_Payment_2021 UNIQUE (InvoiceID, Amount, TransDate, TransTime);
```

FYI, this is happening on a 2012 SQL server.

thanks
Harry

Comment: seems,you need unique filtered index CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_UQ_Pos ON Payments(InvoiceID, Amount, TransDate, TransTime)WHERE Amounts>=0.00

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you @Sergey - the negative amounts properly exist in the table, but I want this UNIQUE CONSTRAINT to only apply to the non-negative amount records. Does this index you propose aid me in that task?

Comment: Technically you are adding a new column to the constraint - Amount? How about just dropping the existing constraint and add a new one? Or are you asking if negative amounts can be part of the constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unique constraint is implemented using a unique index.  You can get the same functionality using a filtered index:

```
create unique index unq_payment_2021 on
    payments(InvoiceID, Amount, TransDate, TransTime)
    where amount >= 0;
```

One slight difference is the error message that you get when the condition is violated.  In one case, it refers to a unique constraint and in another to a unique index.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=91bfe4b8b7af817e351e8c4896600635) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thanks for the help. I'm afraid that I'll need a little more clarity. While I am perfectly fine with queries, stored procs and functions, constraints and indexes are getting into the deep end of the pool for me.  QUESTION: does this unique index prevent multiple negative amounts with the same time stamp from being entered into the table??  Because I cant do that. that has to remain allowed.

Comment: @HarryA just try it yourself and verify if it works or not. Do you actually store rows where amount = 0? Should those be included or excluded from this logic?

Comment: @HarryA, the `WHERE` clause is applied first so the index will not include any rows with negative amounts. The uniqueness of the key columns will be enforced only for amounts >= 0.

Comment: @DanGuzman so then once this is implemented on the table, will the server reject duplicates ONLY for positive amounts? and allow same time stamped multiples where the amount is negative?

Comment: @harrya Yes, dups for positive will be rejected. Positive and zero to be exact.

Comment: thank you to all who aided me in this task. Special thanks to @GordonLinoff . Looks like the clients have been filling their payments data with multiple duplicates for over a decade - there are dozens if not hundreds of violations when I try to implement the INDEX...... the result is I will have to leave the CONSTRAINT/INDEX out of the picture for now.  I'll have to concentrate my efforts on a front end solution to preventing this problem of duplicates from continuing in the future.

Comment: @HarryA . . . Actually, it is possible to create a filtered unique index, where you filter on the date.  That at least prevents new invoices from having duplicates (although it would still allow duplicates on the unfiltered older invoices).

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you expand on your idea of filtering on the date?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - would this be as simple as adding a hardcoded date to the where clause? ie "and Transdate > cast('2021-1-1' as Date);" ?

Comment: @HarryA . . . Yes, that would work for a filtered index that would prevent *new* duplicates on *new* invoices.